# Functional conversion from dictionary to list

Tags: python, functional-programming

I am looking at a functional way to do the following:

```
lst = []
for k, v in dict.iteritems():
    lst.append(my_class(k, v))
return lst
```

Something akin to

```
imap(lambda (k,v): my_class(k, v), [...] dict [...])
```

would be ideal but clearly does not work.

How could I do it?

Comment: In what way does this clearly not work?

Comment: @Marcin: I fail to understand what should go instead of the [...] so I keep getting exceptions.

Comment: Do you like my list comprehension example below, if so please up vote and accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let `d` be a dict and `f` a callable, and given the [`starmap`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) function, the second code could be written:

```
from itertools import starmap
starmap(f, d.iteritems())
```

Or to match your code: `starmap(my_class, dict.iteritems())`

And to actually answer your question, the functional way would be:

```
return list(starmap(my_class, dict.iteritems))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import starmap    
starmap(myclass, thedict.iteritems())
```

The above should work.

Comment: @yi_H: Hence why I altered it to use starmap.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use list comprehension syntax

```
list = [ my_class(k,v) for k, v in dict.iteritems() ]
```

a generator could also be used.

```
 gen = (my_class(k,v) for k, v in dict.iteritems())
```

The generator will not create/run the function my_class(k,v) until it is iterated.

Answer (score 1):

```
map(lambda x: my_class(*x), d.iteritems())
```